What is the proper replacement for Query in Glassmapper V5
We are working on the Sitecore upgrade.
below code that is used in older Glassmapper
  public IEnumerable<ISitecoreItem> GetNavigation()
  {
         var NavigationQuery = "./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templateid='" + Site_FolderConstants.TemplateIdString + "']/Data/Navigation/#Main Navigation#/*";
         IEnumerable<ISitecoreItem> results = Context.SitecoreService.Query<ISitecoreItem>(NavigationQuery);
        return results;
  }


You will need to use GetItemsByQueryOptions to replace the query in order to fetch multiple items from the query.
public IEnumerable<ISitecoreItem> GetNavigation()
{
   var NavigationQuery = "./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templateid='" + Site_FolderConstants.TemplateIdString + "']/Data/Navigation/#Main Navigation#/*";

   GetItemsByQueryOptions builder = new GetItemsByQueryOptions();
   builder.Query = new Query(NavigationQuery);
   builder.RelativeItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;

   IEnumerable<ISitecoreItem> results = Context.SitecoreService.GetItems<ISitecoreItem>(builder);
   return results;
}

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
